# Laravel authentication fails to redirect

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make an auth system to block any access without login but the authenticated method always loads the login page. I override all methods in AuthenticatesUsers because I changed the users' table name and columns but always seem to end up loading the login page. I can return a view in the authenticated method but these will redirect me to the login page if I try to go to another page.

my DB
[image]

my login form

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
<body>
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'Auth\LoginController@login','methode' => 'POST']) }}
    {{Form::text('login', old('username') ?: old('email'),['class'=>''.$errors->has('email')||$errors->has('username') ? 'is-invalid' : ''.' form-control' ,'placeholder'=>'Nom d\'utilisateur ou email' ,'required', 'autofocus'])}}
    @if ($errors->has('username') || $errors->has('email'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') ?: $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
        {{Form::password('mot_de_passe', ['class'=>''.$errors->has('password')? 'is-invalid' : ''.' form-control','placeholder'=>'Mot De Passe' , 'required'])}}
        @if ($errors->has('password'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
        </span>
        @endif
        
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block"><i class="ft-unlock"></i>
        {{ __('Login') }}
    </button>
{{ Form::close() }}
</body>
</html>
```

**PagesController**

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    protected $redirectTo = '/'; // Redirect after successfull login

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function tableau_bord()
    {
        return view('pages.tableau_bord');
    }
}
```

**Methods using when login in LoginController**

```
 class LoginController extends Controller
 {
 protected $redirectTo = '/';

 public function __construct()
 {
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    $this->username = $this->findUsername();
 }
 public function findUsername()
 {
 $login = request()->input('login');

 $fieldType = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 
 'nom_utilisateur';

 request()->merge([$fieldType => $login]);
 return $fieldType;
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}

protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        $this->username => 'required|string',
        'mot_de_passe' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}

protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        array($this->username => $request->login, 'password' =>
            $request > mot_de_passe)
    );
}

protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
        ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect()->to($this->redirectPath());
}

public function redirectPath()
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
        return $this->redirectTo();
    }
    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/';
}

public function redirectTo()
{
    return $this->redirectTo;
}

protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]);
}

public function username()
{
    return $this->username;
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->username(), 'mot_de_passe');
}
}
```

Comment: I think the place where the redirect happens is in `App\Exceptions\Handler` when handling an authentication exception

Comment: so what the solution :/

Comment: Hello Mizo! If I understood you correctly, you need only to deny access for some routes if the user is not logged in. You don't need to override any method. Just use the auth middleware that laravel provides out of the box. You can use it on routes file or on controller construct method. I think you could delete all overrides you've done and test it this way. Please, tell me if it helped or explain a little bit more so I can understand and help you :)

Comment: hi mate i override the methods bcs i changed the user's table name and columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if any one has this problem i solved by rename the table to users and the email/password fields in the DB & login form & loginController & config/auth.php ...
basically back to stage after make:auth command apparently laravel hate change the users table :(